# Unable to Filter based on Substring in Pandas

Tags: pandas

There is a dataset in this form:

```
company_url         Name                  Revenue
mackter.com         Mack Sander           NaN
nientact.com        Neient Dan            321
ventienty.com       Richard               NaN
```

So, my task here is to remove all the rows where string 'tac', 'bux' or 'mvy' is coming in either 'company_url' or 'Name' column.... As you can see, 'tac' is present in nientact.com , so the row should get deleted... Similarly, all the rows where any of these 3 string are present in either company_url or Name, the rows should get deleted.... SO, Initially I tried it for company_url column and written the below code, but it's showing error.

```
lists=['tac', 'bux', 'mvy']
for i in lists:
    df = df[~df['company_url].str.contains(i)]
```

but its showing
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can craft a regex to use with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), then aggregate with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), invert with `~`, and perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import re

lists = ['tac', 'bux', 'mvy']
pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, lists))
# 'tac|bux|mvy'

out = df[~df[['company_url', 'Name']]
          .apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(pattern, case=False))
                            .any(axis=1)
        ]
```

Output:

```
     company_url         Name  Revenue
0    mackter.com  Mack Sander      NaN
2  ventienty.com      Richard      NaN
```

Just for info a fix of your loop, but don't use it as this is inefficient:

```
lists=['tac', 'bux', 'mvy']
for i in lists:
    df = df[~df[['company_url', 'Name']]
               .apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(i))
               .any(axis=1)]

# or

lists=['tac', 'bux', 'mvy']
for i in lists:
    for col in ['company_url', 'Name']:
        df = df[~df[col].str.contains(i)]
```

Comment: Thanks... Your code is working fine... But what's wrong in my code ??? Why it's showing error.. any idea ??

Comment: @Patrik apart for the missing `'` and the fact that you were only checking one column your code was functional (but inefficient)